# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'injection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-16

I am getting following error after upgrading react to 16.x

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'injection' of undefined
    at injectTapEventPlugin (injectTapEventPlugin.js:23)
    at eval (index.js:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1363)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at eval (multi_main:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:589)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at bundle.js:579
    at bundle.js:582
```

Please help!!!

react version --> `"^16.4.2"`
react-tap-event-plugin --> `"^3.0.3"`

Comment: you should have to use like `obk?.injection`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We cannot use react-tap-event-plugin after React 16.4.0

https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin/issues/121